# Suggested Driftwood hardeners or coating

Tags: finishing

I would like to mail out a small collection of Pacific Island (Guam)  Driftwood. I need to completely coat-harden driftwood so U.S.Postal Service WILL let me mail back to the states.  What hardeners do you suggest to keep Post Office happy AND still allow for driftwood to keep some natural appearance?

Comment: Commercial wood hardeners are probably what you should look at. They're intended for toughening up decayed or partly rotted wood and the best of them can take "punky" or spongy wood to a reasonable hardness. I should probably warn you, they can be a bit pricey! Another thing that can be used for this purpose is thin superglue, but obviously this would get expensive quickly for anything other than really very small pieces.

Comment: If you are limited by postal acceptance, ask them... In general, sounds like a thin epoxy (though some are more of an acrylic, IIRC.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.....My brother also suggested a commercial wood sealer. Will shall see that end result is. Then I'll experiment with the wood hardeners. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck with [***Cactus Juice***](https://www.turntex.com/) as a stabilizer and [***Alumilite***](https://www.alumilite.com/) 1/1 casting resin or [***West System***](http://www.westsystem.com/) 5/1 epoxy both work well for filling major voids. A DIY vacuum chamber and a small source of heat via toaster oven, or, I like to vacuum bag/seal and submerse my stabilized product in hot water to set the heat kicked stabilizers.

If its just a small project you could always just saturate it in a high viscosity CA glue, [***Paleo Bond***](http://www.paleobond.com/) would be a specialty brand, loctite, Bob Smith Industries and Hot Stuff are hobby shop brands.